# iOS Project Giving "Automatic Reference Count Issue"

Tags: ios, xcode, methods, compiler-errors, selector

I have inherited an iOS project from a developer that I have no contact with.

When I compile & run the project, almost every .m file is giving me a few errors that say `Receive Type "theFilename" for instance X does not declare a method with selector "otherMethod:"`

I am able to remedy each of these by moving the "otherMethod" up in the code so it is above the point where it is referenced... but this whole situation seems odd because (allegedly) this is the code that was submitted and is functional in the App Store.

My thought is I am missing some setting in my XCode that is causing this problem.

Any thoughts or ideas about how to fix this without having the doctor every file, would be appreciated.

Comment: Is ARC enabled in your project settings?

Comment: This isn't what you asked for, but it is probably an improvement.

Rather than move the code up, it is probably better to declare the methods.

Since these methods aren't declared in the header, you can keep them private by declaring them in a null category ( I think that is what it is), as done by Apple in some of there more recent template code.

    (at)interface MyViewController ()
        // stick declarations in here.
    (at)end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARC disable:
Click on you project, in the left hand organizer.
Select your target, in the next column over.
Select the Build Settings tab at the top.
Scroll down to "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" (it may be listed as "CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC" under the User-Defined settings group),
and set it to NO.

ARC enable:
Open your project and select Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC. This will start checking your code if it is ready for the conversion.

Comment: So how did they have this running before? It seems like half the code user ARC and half does not.